# How to show a marker on map by using latitude and longitude retrieved from firebase database in htlm and java script

Tags: javascript, dictionary, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, marker

I am retrieving latitude and longitude from firebase database. The values are being stored in variables, i.e latitude and longitude. But when I tried to use these values to set a marker on map it does not work, but when I give static latitude and location the marker appears. Help me please. Thanks

Here is the code of html file which I use to retrieve the location and show it on the map.
`

```
      <head>
            <title>Data From Firebase Database</title>
<!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >   -->
<style>
#map{

    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class= ""mainDiv" align= "left">
<h1> Locations </h1>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Latitude</td>
<td>Longitude</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="table_body">
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script src= "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.3.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script>

var config = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyCU7LWliFjX7iWtNkZHhuZI0jvih6rffFI",
authDomain: "test26sep-eae46.firebaseio.com",
databaseURL: "https://test26sep-eae46.firebaseio.com/",
storageBucket: "test26sep-eae46.appspot.com",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();

rootRef.on("child_added", snap =>{

var latitude = snap.child("latitude").val();
var longitude = snap.child("longitude").val();
initMap(latitude,longitude);

$("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + latitude + "</td><td>" + longitude + "</td></tr>");

});

</script>

<h1>Map</h1>
<div id="map"></div>

    <script>

function initMap(latitude,longitude){


//alert('Values have been gathered click ok to show map !! Welcome Taj , from Arslan !! :PP');
var options = {
    zoom: 8,
        center: {lat: 31.5546,lng:74.3572}
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);



//show an alert to check if the values are being fetched from firebase database stored in latitude and longitude.
  alert (latitude + " " + longitude);


var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:{lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
        map:map,
      });

      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content:'<h4>Lahore</h4>'
      });

      marker.addListener('click', function(){
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });

}
    </script>

    <script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD0w2dY7OZvF6nBvnLLxzAzXi05l_8jc-o">


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: Try `initMap(parseFloat(latitude), parseFloat(longitude));`  Using `.val()` will return you the values as strings, I think

Comment: Thank you so much my fried @duncan . it worked. you made my day.
`position:{lat: parseFloat(latitude), lng: parseFloat(longitude)},`

Comment: Cool; I'll post that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

So where you do:

```
var latitude = snap.child("latitude").val();
var longitude = snap.child("longitude").val();
```

Those values are being returned from `.val()` as strings.  You have to convert them to numbers to work with Google Maps.

Just do:

```
initMap(parseFloat(latitude), parseFloat(longitude));
```

Or, where you use them with the Maps API, e.g.

```
position:{lat: parseFloat(latitude), lng: parseFloat(longitude)}
```

Comment: Perfect @duncan